# How can I display font awesome icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, font-awesome

I am trying to display font awesome icons, but it's not working.

I tried to link the font awesome cdn like this.

```
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl.'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

and displayed like this:    `<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="false">   </i>`

but it's not working. I expect to get the search icon displayed on the screen.

Comment: Why you're using `$baseUrl` as a prefix for absolute URL?

Comment: to link the bootstrap...

Comment: @Sibghat he is telling you to remove that `$baseUrl` which you should as the path you are providing is to the live link. you dont need that

Comment: where you use this code <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="false">   </i>
please provide more code

Answer (score 0):

My friend just like in the comments :

```
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerCssFile('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

It's enough, in the controller or on the top of the renderFile, then you will be able to use de icon.